# Z-Normalized Euclidean Distance Derivation

Tags: metric-spaces

I am going through this paper:

http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/PID4481997_extend_Matrix%20Profile_I.pdf

And on Page 4, it is claimed that the squared z-normalized euclidean distance between two vectors of equal length, `Q` and `T[i]`, (the latter of which is just the ith subsequence of a longer 1D array, `T`) can be calculated from:

[image]

Here, `m` is the length of `Q` (or `T[i]`), `mu_Q` is the mean of `Q`, `M_T[i]` is the mean for the ith subsequence of `T`, `sigma_Q` is the standard deviation of `Q`, `sigma_T[i]` is the standard deviation for the ith subsequence of `T`, and `Q.T[i]` is the dot product between `Q` and `T[i]`.

I am attempting to derive this equation from first principals but can't see to reconcile the final steps:

[image]

In this case, the summation loops through each element of either `T[i]` or `Q`. Also, recall that:

[image]

I've gotten as close as this but it's not quite right:

[image]

**A semi-related question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296292/pearson-correlation-and-metric-properties).**

Answer (score 0):

I define a few symbols for brevity:

$$ X = T[i] $$
$$ µ_X = M_{T[i]} $$
$$ \sigma_{X} = \Sigma_{T[i]} $$

Starting from your first line in your second block:

$$ = 2m \biggl( 1 - { Q \cdot X - \sum x_i µ_Q - \sum µ_X Q_i + m µ_Q µ_X   \over m \sigma_Q \sigma_X} \biggr) $$

$$ = 2m \biggl( 1 - { Q \cdot X - m µ_Q { 1 \over m} \sum x_i - m µ_X { 1 \over m } \sum Q_i + m µ_Q µ_X   \over m \sigma_Q \sigma_X} \biggr) $$

$$ = 2m \biggl( 1 - { Q \cdot X - m µ_Q µ_X - m µ_X µ_Q + m µ_Q µ_X \over m \sigma_Q \sigma_X} \biggr) $$

$$ = 2m \biggl( 1 - { Q \cdot X - m µ_Q µ_X  \over m \sigma_Q \sigma_X} \biggr) $$